# How do I load MNIST data into a Google Colab Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, mnist

I've got a working environment for running Keras on Google Colab, but cannot figure out how to load MNIST data so I can import it into my program. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Keras has built-in functions to load the MNIST dataset.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Wow, thanks, I had no idea about that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keras has built-in common [datasets](https://keras.io/datasets/) and MNIST is one of them:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

So if you have Keras on Colab, you should also have MNIST ready to go.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Pardon my ignorance, wasn't expecting it to be so convenient!